# Django: Using 2 different AdminSite instances with different models registered

Tags: django, django-admin

Apart from the usual admin, I want to create a limited admin for non-staff users. This admin site will have different registered `ModelAdmin`s.

I created a folder /useradmin/ in my project directory and similar to contrib/admin/_*init_*.py I added an autodiscover() which will register models defined in useradmin.py modules instead of admin.py:

```
# useradmin/__init__.py
def autodiscover():
# Same as admin.autodiscover() but registers useradmin.py modules
...
for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    mod = import_module(app)
    try:
        before_import_registry = copy.copy(site._registry)
        import_module('%s.useradmin' % app)
    except:
        site._registry = before_import_registry
        if module_has_submodule(mod, 'useradmin'):
            raise
```

I also cretated sites.py under useradmin/ to override AdminSite similar to contrib/admin/sites:

```
# useradmin/sites.py
class UserAdminSite(AdminSite):
    def has_permission(self, request):
        # Don't care if the user is staff
        return request.user.is_active

    def login(self, request):
        # Do the login stuff but don't care if the user is staff
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            ...
        else:
            ...

site = UserAdminSite(name='useradmin')
```

In the project's URLs:

```
# urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
import useradmin

admin.autodiscover()
useradmin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^useradmin/', include(useradmin.site.urls)),
)
```

And I try to register different models in admin.py and useradmin.py modules under app directories:

```
# products/useradmin.py
import useradmin
class ProductAdmin(useradmin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
useradmin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

But when registering models in useradmin.py like `useradmin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)`, I get `'module' object has no attribute 'ModelAdmin'` exception. Though when I try this via shell;

```
import useradmin
from useradmin import ModelAdmin
```

does not raise any exception.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**Edit:**

I tried going the @Luke way and arranged the code as follows as minimal as possible:
(file paths are relative to the project root)

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib.admin import autodiscover
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
user_site = AdminSite(name='useradmin')

# urls.py (does not even have url patterns; just calls autodiscover())
import admin
admin.autodiscover()

# products/admin.py
import admin
from products.models import Product
admin.user_site.register(Product)
```

As a result I get an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'user_site'` when `admin.user_site.register(Product)` in `products/admin.py` is called.

Any ideas?

**Solution:**

I don't know if there are better ways but, renaming the `admin.py` in the project root to `useradmin.py` and updating the imports accordingly resolved the last case, which was a naming and import conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `useradmin` have a `ModelAdmin` class defined, or do you import it from `contrib.admin`? I don't see anywhere in the code you supplied where that class gets set up.

That being said, there's a **much** easier way to do this: just [initialize two AdminSites](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects), and then wire them up to the URLs that you want (You can even put them [in the same urlconf](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#multiple-admin-sites-in-the-same-urlconf)).

Comment: the ModelAdmin is imported from the `contrib.admin` from within useradmin/__init__.py. the import statements in useradmin/__init__.py and contrib.admin.__init__.py are identical. thus i can import the ModelAdmin like `from useradmin import ModelAdmin`. i want some customization beyond the way told in the docs. for example the user should not see some look-up models in the admin main page while having permission to add into them via FK fields. so i need to implement my own autodiscover() to register only some models to the users' admin site.

Comment: You can register only some models to each `AdminSite` instance (the only thing `autodiscover` does for you is find `admin.py` files), without having to do all of this duplication - you can even just write your own `AdminSite` class that inherits from Django's, so that you can set it up how you want.

Comment: so i can define another AdminSite instance like `user_admin = AdminSite(name='user_admin')` and register some models with the original `admin.site.register(ModelA)` and some with `admin.user_site(ModelB)`. that makes sense. but i still could figure out how in practice. i am running into circular import problems. i will post code snippets if/when i manage to get this rolling. thanks.

Comment: the last case appears to be a naming conflict. i changed the `admin.py` in the project root to `useradmin.py` and updated the imports accordingly. now it works as expected. thanks.